# XPath to return all ANCESTORS until

Tags: xslt, xpath

This is a variant on the common request for an XPath to return all siblings until some condition, answered with characteristic fullness by Dimitre Novatchev at [XPath axis, get all following nodes until](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767430) using this pattern:

```
$x/following-sibling::p
   [1 = count(preceding-sibling::node()[name() = name($x)][1] | $x)]
```

But that pattern relies on the symmetry of `following-sibling` and `preceding-sibling`, on the ability to look in both directions along an axis.

Is there a comparable pattern when the axis is `ancestor-or-self`?

For example:

```
<t>
  <a xml:base="/news/" >
    <b xml:base="reports/">
      <c xml:base="politics/" />
      <c xml:base="sports/" >
        <d xml:base="reports/" />
        <d xml:base="photos/" >
          <img url="A1.jpg" />
          <img url="A2.jpg" />
        </d>
      </c>
      <c xml:base="entertainment" />
    </b>
  </a>
</t>
```

The straighforward

```
<xsl:template match="img">

    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[@xml:base]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@xml:base"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>

</xsl:template>
```

would return

```
 /news/reports/sports/photos/A1.jpg
 /news/reports/sports/photos/A1.jpg
```

but if

```
      <c xml:base="sports/" >
```

were instead

```
      <c xml:base="/sports/" >
```

with that leading `/`, the `for-each` needs to stop, so as to return

```
 /sports/photos/A1.jpg
 /sports/photos/A2.jpg
```

How (in XSLT/XPath 1.0) to make it stop?

Comment: My idea was to test for count(elements meeting the condition, from the starting element on up) = count(elements meeting the condition, from the candidate on up). But my attempts to code that failed.

Comment: What exactly nodes do you want to select? It isn't specified in the question.

Comment: The ancestor nodes from the matching img element up to, but no further than, one that matches some condition, here an @xml:base that begins with a /.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pWanted" select="//img"/>
 <xsl:param name="pWantedAttr" select="'url'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$pWanted"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(starts-with(@xml:base, '/'))]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[@xml:base][1]"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@xml:base,@*[name()=$pWantedAttr])"/>
  <xsl:if test="not(@xml:base)"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@xml:base, '/')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="@xml:base"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to this XML document**:

```
<t>
  <a xml:base="/news/" >
    <b xml:base="reports/">
      <c xml:base="politics/" />
      <c xml:base="/sports/" >
        <d xml:base="reports/" />
        <d xml:base="photos/" >
          <img url="A1.jpg" />
          <img url="A2.jpg" />
        </d>
      </c>
      <c xml:base="entertainment" />
    </b>
  </a>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
/sports/photos/A1.jpg
/sports/photos/A2.jpg
```

---

**Update -- A single XPath 2.0 expression solution**:

```
   for $target in //img,
       $top in $target/ancestor::*[starts-with(@xml:base,'/')][1]
    return
      string-join(
         (
             $top/@xml:base
           , $top/descendant::*
                [@xml:base and . intersect $target/ancestor::*]
                   /@xml:base
           , $target/@url,
           '&#xA;'
        ),
        ''
                )
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
      "for $target in //img,
           $top in $target/ancestor::*[starts-with(@xml:base,'/')][1]
        return
          string-join(
             (
                 $top/@xml:base
               , $top/descendant::*
                    [@xml:base and . intersect $target/ancestor::*]
                       /@xml:base
               , $target/@url,
               '&#xA;'
            ),
            ''
                    )
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<t>
  <a xml:base="/news/" >
    <b xml:base="reports/">
      <c xml:base="politics/" />
      <c xml:base="sports/" >
        <d xml:base="reports/" />
        <d xml:base="photos/" >
          <img url="A1.jpg" />
          <img url="A2.jpg" />
        </d>
      </c>
      <c xml:base="entertainment" />
    </b>
  </a>
</t>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result from this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
/news/reports/sports/photos/A1.jpg
 /news/reports/sports/photos/A2.jpg
```

**With the modified document**:

```
<t>
  <a xml:base="/news/" >
    <b xml:base="reports/">
      <c xml:base="politics/" />
      <c xml:base="/sports/" >
        <d xml:base="reports/" />
        <d xml:base="photos/" >
          <img url="A1.jpg" />
          <img url="A2.jpg" />
        </d>
      </c>
      <c xml:base="entertainment" />
    </b>
  </a>
</t>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
/sports/photos/A1.jpg
 /sports/photos/A2.jpg
```

---

**Update2**:

The OP has suggested this simplification:

> Update added by original poster: Once embedded in the full
>   application, where the full url replaced the relative one, Dimitre's
>   approach ended up being this simple

:

```
<xsl:template match="@url">
    <xsl:attribute name="url">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="uri" select=".." />
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*"  mode="uri">
    <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(@xml:base, '/'))">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[@xml:base][1]" mode="uri"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@xml:base"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Every time I think I'm finally grokking XSLT, Dimitre takes me to a whole new level! (I wonder why this kind of recursion works for the ancestor axis, but not with the sibling axis.)

Comment: @JPM, You are welcome. The reason things are slightly different for siblings is that there is no "preceding-sibling-or-self::" and no "following-sibling-or-self" axis.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I need 1.0. As you can guess, I need a little routine to resolve relative URIs. So I'm now extending your nice 1.0 approach to handle the rest of the resolution.

Comment: @JPM, Yes, I know. I made this update to show what is a truly "single XPath expression" that also solves the problem, so that the reader would not be confused by claims that aren't really a "single XPath expression solution".

Comment: @Dimitre, I suggested a postscript to your answer. Reject the addition if you want and I'll put it into the OP.

Comment: @JPM, This is a nice simplification. However, this won't work if not all the ancestors have the attribute `xml:base`. I will add a similar edit, clearly stating the assumption that all ancestors in the chain do have an `xml:base` attribute.

Comment: @Dimitre, Why must all have xml:base? It's working fine for me when they don't. And with a couple small additions, I got a complete resolver of relative uri paths in a ten-line template. Shazam!

Comment: @Dimitre, you removed that comment where you said something nice about my improvement. Darn. That was the closest I figure I'll ever get to answering a SO question on XSLT! :) (Thanks again for your help.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to select the right nodes in a single for-each select expression:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="img">
    <xsl:for-each select="
      ancestor-or-self::*[
        starts-with(@xml:base, '/')
      ][1]/descendant-or-self::*[
        @xml:base and .//img[generate-id() = generate-id(current())]
      ]">
      <xsl:value-of select="@xml:base"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given this input XML:

```
<t>
  <a xml:base="/news/" >
    <b xml:base="reports/">
      <c xml:base="politics/" />
      <c xml:base="/sports/" >
        <d xml:base="reports/" />
        <d xml:base="photos/" >
          <img url="A1.jpg" />
          <img url="A2.jpg" />
        </d>
      </c>
      <c xml:base="entertainment" />
    </b>
  </a>
</t>
```

The correct result is produced:

```
/sports/photos/A1.jpg
/sports/photos/A2.jpg
```

The XPath expression could be read as "Beginning with the closest ancestor whose `@xml:base` starts with a slash, select that and all of its descendants who have the current `<img>` as one of *their* descendants."

This effectively selects exactly the one correct path down into the XML tree.

Comment: Tomalak, "One single XPath expression" ??? I see *four* XPath expressions here, not to mention that they are part of complex XSLT processing. Please, correct your statement. It should be possible to produce the wanted results with a truly single XPath 2.0 expression.

Comment: @Dimitre An XPath expression can contain more sub-expressions. It still is a single expression. I don't see anything to correct. As an aside, it is entirely unnecessary to post the same comment twice on this website.

Comment: I understood what was meant with "one", and I can see this being a fine approach in the right situation. So a +1 (though no checkmark) from me. I'd be concerned that this would not scale nicely to large trees, with that .//img in there. Or maybe a key on the id would alleviate that.

Comment: Tomalak, If this is "a single XPath expression", then please, post just a single XPath expression -- not a transformation with a template, `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:value-of`. For example, see the expression I am going to add to my answer in the next few minutes.

Comment: @JPM I'm not sure a key would be possible. There is no value that you could use to identify the right descendant `<img>` when your context is at one of its ancestors. You are right about your performance considerations, this will not scale nicely to very deep trees. I merely posted the solution as one that works in the spirit of the `following-sibling`/`preceding-sibling` expression in your question.

Comment: Tomalak, One has a "single XPath expression solution" when one can execute it with a DOM Evaluate() method, and/or with XQuery. Please, show us such a single XPath expression solution -- the code in your answer currently fails this test.

Comment: @Dimitre Can you explain what, exactly, is the legal contents of the `<xsl:for-each>` `select` attribute? Maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: Tomalak, see my previous comment. To answer your question, the XPath expression specified in the `select` attribute of the `xsl:for-each` instruction in your code, *selects nodes* -- it doesn't produce the wanted (string) result.

Comment: @Dimitre But you agree that it is one single XPath expression in the select attribute? Good. I'm not sure what we are arguing about, then. I did not imply that XPath was all you need, that's your interpretation of my words. But I've changed my wording. EOD.

Comment: Tomalak, To understand what "single XPath expression solution" means, see the update to my answer. This is an Xpath expression, which can be executed with a standalone Evaluate() (or similarly named) method from any PL. And/or it can be executed by XQuery. Most importantly, the result of the evaluation must be the exactly wanted result. So, no further processing of the result of the evaluation is required. The now modified text in your answer seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

I found it: Count the ancestors that meet the condition *before* going into the for-each loop. Test each candidate to see if the count of its condition-matching ancestors is the same.

This stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="img">

        <xsl:variable name="distance" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*[@xml:base][substring(@xml:base,1,1)='/'])" />

        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[@xml:base][
            count(ancestor-or-self::*[@xml:base][substring(@xml:base,1,1)='/'])=$distance
            ]">
                <xsl:value-of select="@xml:base"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to the given XML

```
<t>
    <a xml:base="/news/" >
        <b xml:base="reports/">
            <c xml:base="politics/" />
            <c xml:base="/sports/" >
                <d xml:base="reports/" />
                <d xml:base="photos/" >
                    <img url="A1.jpg" />
                    <img url="A2.jpg" />
                </d>
            </c>
            <c xml:base="entertainment" />
        </b>
    </a>
</t>
```

returns the desired result:

```
                /sports/photos/A1.jpg
                /sports/photos/A2.jpg
```

Without the `/` before `sports`, the for-each matches ancestors all the way to `/news`:

```
                /news/reports/sports/photos/A1.jpg
                /news/reports/sports/photos/A2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

With a minor change to your original template:

```
<xsl:template match="img">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[@xml:base][not(.//*[starts-with(@xml:base, '/')])]">
         <xsl:value-of select="@xml:base"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
</xsl:template>
```