# Wrapping a series of sibling elements

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Using ruby/nokogiri I would like to wrap some elements starting at one element and ending before the next one of those elements. So lets say I have:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

And I want to wrap all foos and their contiguous bars (if there are any) in a baz class that closes before the next foo (last one obvs doesn't have another foo), like this:

```
<div class="baz">
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="baz">
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="baz">
    <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
<div class="baz">
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Edit: I found this that asks a similar question but I'm struggling to adapt it [XPath axis, get all following nodes until](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767430/xpath-axis-get-all-following-nodes-until)

Edit 2:This will return the bars after the foo but not the foo:

```
body.xpath("(//div[@class='foo'])[1]/following-sibling::div[@class='bar']
    [1 = count(preceding-sibling::div[@class='foo'][1] | (//div[@class='foo'])[1])]")
```

Need to figure out how to include the foo!

Edit 3: Welp this will add the foo:

```
body.xpath("//div[@class='foo'][1]","//div[@class='foo']
    [1]/following-sibling::div[@class='bar']
    [1 = count(preceding-sibling::div[@class='foo'][1] | (//div[@class='foo'])[1])]")
```

But the bigger problem is I'm not sure how to iterate this? It just returns the first set of foo + bars.

Edit 4: Iterating through the foo-bar chunks:

```
var = 1
loop do 
  chunk = body.xpath("//div[@class='foo'][#{var}]","//div[@class='foo']
    [#{var}]/following-sibling::div[@class='bar']
    [1 = count(preceding-sibling::div[@class='foo'][#{var}] | 
    (//div[@class='foo'])[1])]")
  puts chunk
  var += 1
  break if chunk.length == 0
end
```

Not sure how to wrap them in divs now.

Answer (score 0):

Welp I have a likely inelegant solution for the followers of this insanely popular question:

```
var = 1
loop do 
  chunk = body.xpath("//div[@class='foo'][#{var}]","//div[@class='foo']
    [#{var}]/following-sibling::div[@class='bar']
    [1 = count(preceding-sibling::div[@class='foo'][#{var}] | 
    (//div[@class='foo'])[1])]")
  break if chunk.length == 0      
  var += 1
  puts <div class="baz">
  puts chunk
  puts </div>
end
```